# While registering DPM getting TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:6049

Tags: azure, azure-functions, vmware, azure-backup-vault, dpm

When I register the DPM getting error " The activation did not complete successfully"
When I saw the AutoUpadte Error code it was getting:- TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:6049.
And in CBEngine I as getting error :- AcsTokenRequestClientError
can any one please help

Tried to with reinstalled MARS agent but dint work

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-dpm-introduction#:~:text=Install%20the%20agent%20on%20the%20DPM%20server%20as,After%20the%20agent%20is%20installed%2C%20Close%20the%20window.

Comment: Yes i have configured according to the document. When i check the error i got the below error :- AcsTokenRequestClientError and also getting error DLS - 100089